# Can't see my project in Jupiter notebook anymore

Tags: jupyter-notebook

[image]

I'm trying to use Jupyter notebook from my windows 10 machine but, when I start it, I get this screen where I can't see my project anymore, I cant navigate anywhere nor I can create any new project. The weird thing is that up to yesterday it was working fine and I don't recall installing/uninstalling or changing anything.

Anyone can help me get through it?

Comment: it would be helpful to know how you installed it (VM, Docker, local). As well as details like your OS.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, So I have a windows 10 machine and I usually run jupyter notebook through the Anaconda Navigator. I also tried to start it from the  anaconda powershell promt but I get the same outcome. Please ask any question will help clarify the situation (and also how to get most of these informations because I know very little about it)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
It is a bug in the latest update to jupyter notebooks.  The workaround is to downgrade back to the most recent working copy. I really wanted a way that used conda and not pip to downgrade, and I found an excellent solution.
Anaconda keeps an archive of previous releases of the entire system (conda + jupyter + spyder + ...).  You can find the archive here:

`https://repo.continuum.io/archive/`

For me, the version that worked was the July 2019 release

`https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-2019.07-Windows-x86_64.exe`

First you must uninstall Anaconda completely and then install the archived version.